# Ubuntu 10.04 LTS not detecting Ethernet

Tags: server, networking

HP Compaq 6200 Pro MT desktop machine. I installed Ubuntu 10.04.3 LTS server edition. The installer said that it could not detect the network hardware, despite an ethernet cable being plugged in and a link light showing; I tested the cable/connection/node on another machine and it works. I completed the installation, but Ubuntu does not detect the ethernet card. `lspci` shows the card, but reports `<access denied>` for some of the specifications.

I booted off a CrunchBang Linux (Debian-based) live USB and it detects the network card and I get an IP address.

Rebooted into Ubuntu server -- no network connectivity on the ethernet card.

Suggestions?

**Update:** Installed Debian 6.0.3 (CD1) from USB. It detected the network card during installation and configured the network. I rebooted into Debian and network was working; the machine has an IP address.

Comment: well you already found out that you can use lspci to find out which networking card it is - please let us know as well :-)

Comment: Ethernet controller: Inter Corporation Device 1502 (rev 04); Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 1497

Comment: Debian install also shows `access denied` as the Ubuntu one did, but provides more information about the NIC. It's an Intel 82579LM using kernel driver e1000e.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ubuntu 10.04 LTS does not support the Intel 82579LM NIC as detailed [here](http://fosiao.com/node/18); instructions on downloading and installing the driver are provided there too. An expired bug report on this issue is [here](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/155696).